# @JvmStatic used for @Provides function in an object class

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

```kotlin
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides

@Module
object MyModule {
    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun provideHelloWorld(): String {
        return "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

Above is my code. But AndroidStudio says "@JvmStatic used for @Provides function in an object class". What is the reason?

Comment: Never used dagger, but sounds to me like you don't need to put JvmStatic in that situation: https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.25.2

Comment: Thx for answer. I solved my curiosity.